# CDC PostgreSQL with Debezium while ignoring columns

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a postgreSQL table with 10 columns, we need to enable CDC on this table to capture changes only in ONE of the columns ignoring the other nine. Our debezium has the following configurations:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.history.file.filename": "/data/postgresql-d-connection-teste3-history.dat",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "database.dbname": "postgres",
    "max.queue.size": "81290",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "transforms": "Reroute",
    "database.server.name": "xxxx",
    "offset.flush.timeout.ms": "60000",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*)",
    "buffer.memory": "2048",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "plugin.name": "wal2json",
    "offset.flush.interval.ms": "10000",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "teste3",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "database.hostname": "xxxx",
    "database.password": "xxxx",
    "name": "postgresql-d-connection-teste3",
    "table.include.list": "public.test",
    "max.batch.size": "20480",
    "database.history": "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory"
}
```

We also already tried to set these parameters in the JSON, without success:

```
"column.include.list": "public.test.{id|name}"
"column.exclude.list": "public.test.{id|name}"
```

I have the same scenario working fine with MS SQL Server, where I only had to execute these query:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema = N'xxxx', 
@source_name   = N'xxxx',
@captured_column_list = N'col1, col2, col3
@supports_net_changes = 0
```

**Is it possible to achieve the same goal with postgreSQL?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `column.*.list` properties take comma-separated values, not this format of `{id|name}`

Comment: I tried using this format too, but it didn't work

Comment: it only removes the column from the message, but I get the message itself

Comment: @MarcosApps any luck so far? I am facing similar issue, column.exclude.list removes the excluded field from the message, but any change in excluded columns still add a new message to the topic.

Comment: for regex use `dbo\\.\\w+\\.(col1|col2)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the setting you need

> skip.messages.without.change

Specifies whether to skip publishing messages when there is no change in included columns. This would essentially filter messages if there is no change in columns included as per column.include.list or column.exclude.list properties.

Strait from documentation
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-skip-messages-without-change